# Extract msg attachments from outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have the following vba code that saves attachments in an email.

This works fine for .docx, .jpg etc but I need to use it to extract multiple .msg attachments which doesn't work.

The code is

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "C:\Test\"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
stFileName = saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
i = 0
JumpHere:
If Dir(stFileName) = "" Then
objAtt.SaveAsFile stFileName
Else
i = i + 1
stFileName = saveFolder & "\" & i & " - " & objAtt.DisplayName
GoTo JumpHere
End If
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

The error concerns the line - If Dir(stFileName) = "" Then

Comment: You **really should not use** the `GoTo`statement in VBA ! Here is a discussion to illustrate : http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32608532/goto-statement-in-vba.aspx

Comment: Thanks - looks like back to the drawing board...

Comment: @Haribo83: maybe we can help you designing what you were trying to do. Can you explain us the purpose of this part of the code ?

Comment: I have an email backup system I need to clear of emails.  They only way to do this is to send them all as attachments in an email, 100 at a time.

Comment: I then want to save each .msg attachment in a file and use an outlook rule to delete the email.  Does this sound possible?

Comment: seems like quite a complicated solution but let's say you have no other way out, i'll try to use your code and answer you

Comment: @JMax let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1015/discussion-between-haribo83-and-jmax)

Answer (score 1):

Following our chat, here is the final code :

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
Dim saveFolder As String 
Dim i As Integer 

saveFolder = "C:\Test\" 
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments 
  stFileName = saveFolder & objAtt.FileName 
  i = 0 
  'Loop to find the first available filename 
  Do While Dir(stFileName) <> "" 
    i = i + 1 
    stFileName = saveFolder & i & " - " & objAtt.FileName 
  Loop
  objAtt.SaveAsFile stFileName 
Next 
End Sub
```

Regards,

Max

Comment: +1 but note that `While...Wend` is deprecated. VBA help: "The Do...Loop statement provides a more structured and flexible way to perform looping." To "emulate" `While...Wend`, use `Do While...Loop`.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François for pointing it out to me. i'll edit my post to correct it.